# AppleScript - how do I select a menu item in a pop up button that has no title?

Tags: firefox, applescript

Relatively new to AppleScript here...

I'm trying to create an AppleScript to automate a File/Save Page As... action in Firefox. Specifically, I need to select "Web Page, complete" from the Save As... dialog instead of the default "All Files" selection in the pop up button at the bottom of the dialog box.  (I'm using Firefox and this option specifically because I want to save the current html contents after some JavaScript code has run - to parse out values for subsequent processing).

I've been able to hack my way around this problem by selecting the pop up menu (which has no title) by using:

```
((pop up buttons of window "Save As") whose description is "All Files")
```

and by sending the key stroke "w" to select "Web Page, complete" in the pop-up menu.

I'm trying to find a more robust way of doing this instead of relying upon the fact that "w" selects the menu item that I want. I tried:

```
click menu item "Web Page, complete" of 
    ((pop up buttons of window "Save As") whose description is "All Files")
```

but that didn't work. In looking at Accessibility Inspector, it looks like there is a menu between the pop up button (drop down list) and the menu item but I can't figure out how to refer to it.

Any help would be appreciated.  Here's the full script:

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
delay 0.25

    tell application "System Events"

        tell process "Firefox"
            set frontmost to true

            click menu item "Save Page As…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            delay 0.25

            repeat until window "Save As" exists
                delay 0.5
            end repeat

            click ((pop up buttons of window "Save As") whose description is "All Files")
            delay 0.5

            -- This didn't work:
            click menu item "Web Page, complete" of ((pop up buttons of window "Save As") whose description is "All Files")

            -- This works but only because the first entry is "Web Page, complete"
            keystroke "w"
            keystroke return
            delay 0.5

            set outputfilename to "foo3.html" as text

            keystroke outputfilename
            keystroke return

            delay 0.5
      end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
activate application "Firefox"

tell application "System Events"

    tell process "Firefox"
        set frontmost to true
        click menu item "Save Page As…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        repeat until window "Save As" exists
            delay 0.2
        end repeat

        tell window "Save As"
            tell pop up button 1 of group 1
                if value is not "Web Page, complete" then
                    click
                    delay 0.5
                    pick menu item "Web Page, complete" of menu 1
                end if
            end tell

            set outputfilename to "foo3.html"
            keystroke outputfilename
            click button "Save"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```